# Move content left and right on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to move content left and right using on click event and need to stop by margins on the left or right. `list-item`s generating dynamically. Here is the code I tried so far but no worth. By my code it is moving the container left and right. But I need to move `list-item`s left and right.

How can I do this.?

```js
function moveList(px) {
  $('.list').animate({
    'marginLeft': px
  });
}
```

```css
.list {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 25px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
#right-arrow {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(img/right-arrow.png) no-repeat #000;
}
#left-arrow {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(img/left-arrow.png) no-repeat #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="right-arrow" onclick="moveList('-=50px')"></div>
<div id="left-arrow" onclick="moveList('+=50px')"></div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">1</div>
  <div class="list-item">2</div>
  <div class="list-item">3</div>
  <div class="list-item">4</div>
  <div class="list-item">5</div>
  <div class="list-item">6</div>
  <div class="list-item">7</div>
  <div class="list-item">8</div>
  <div class="list-item">9</div>
  <div class="list-item">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `paddingLeft` instead of `marginLeft` perhaps?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan same output

Comment: Are you trying to rearrange the `list-item`s ?

Comment: No. Arrangement is fine. I need to move list items left and right using left click and right click. As well stop click when list items came to the margins.

Comment: adding and removing px is just zooming in and out your div

Answer (score 0):

Try script like this:

```
function moveList(px) {
  $(".list-item:first-child").animate({
    'marginLeft': px
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier for you if you create a element that wraps the `.list-items` with:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
```

Then, instead of modify the margin, you should modify the `left` value.

If you want to use semmantic content for your web it's better to use another HTML structure, not only `div`. For example:

```
<nav> <!-- As this is containing page navigation elements-->
    <ol> <!-- As this is an ordered list of elements-->
        <li> <!-- Each list element-->
            First element
        </li>
        <li>
          Second element
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply translate them.

Define this (given that `clicker` is the selector for your click event).

```
var xValue = -5;
$("#clicker").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".list-item").css("transform","translateX("+xValue+")");
    xValue -= 5;
});
```

Translate will not mess with your markup, and only move the objects it's working on to the left (in this case).
By keeping `xValue` you can keep moving them to the left by repeatedly clicking `clicker`.